# error 500 when I try to download from emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, apache, .htaccess

I confuse why I can't download from emulator. from website i can download the file successful. but from emulator it appear error 500

this is the message that i got

> Server error! the server encountered an internal error and was unable
>   to complete your request. either the server is overloaded or there was
>   an error in a CGI script. if you think this is a server error, please
>   contact the webmaster.
>
> ERROR 500
>   10.0.2.2 Apache/2.2.17(win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

this is my download config.java

```
public class Kondownload {

    String urlKarismaLearning= "http://10.0.2.2/";
    public Kondownload(String urlml){
        urlKarismaLearning = urlKarismaLearning+urlml;
    }
    public String getUrl(){

        return urlKarismaLearning;
    }
}
```

this is my download.java to show the link

```
package mobile.download;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import mobile.config.Kondownload;

import com.karismaelearning.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DownloadText extends Activity{
    public Kondownload linkurl;
    String url;
    String SERVER_URL;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.linkdownload);

        TextView mTextLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LinkDownload);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        String param1 = bundle.getString("keyIdc");
        String param2 = bundle.getString("keyReference");
        linkurl = new Kondownload("moodledata/"+param1+"/"+param2);
        SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();

        mTextLink.setText(SERVER_URL);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(SERVER_URL);

       Linkify.addLinks(mTextLink, pattern, "");

    }
}
```

i already put internet permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

my .htaccess - before i edited

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
```

.htaccess after i edited

```
order deny,allow
allow from all
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

please help me.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete Your .htaccess file,

set AllowOverride All and order in httpd.conf only

Comment: It success the error 500 not appear!!! it can started download but why the download failed? O.o

Comment: the logcat says : no handler for this download type. what i must add to my code? O.o

Comment: the type of file are pdf and doc.

Comment: mostly my file type that I use is PDF, and I have more question. I have link for video, the link redirect user to youtube but when I click the link Access is forbidden and error 403.. why is that? thank you

Comment: what I mut add to my code? O.o I don't have any idea can you help me please? thank you

Comment: I have no idea about this error. Write new question with this problem and post there full code and logcat output. Maybe someone else will now what it means.

Comment: Gustek, i wanna ask again about .htacces. every time i run my application after i shutdown my comp and open eclipse and run the apps the .htaccess is automatically appear in my folder, so the error 500 comes up again. and i delete again .htaccess every time. how to solve this problem? O.o must i delete it every time? thank you

Comment: I don't know Your server setup but auto-creation of .htaccess is not default behaviour for any know to me tool. You have to find out what creates this file and switch it off.

Comment: Gustek, thank you very much for you help. Gustek, I have another question in here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015821/unable-connect-to-server-from-application-on-device , if you can, please look at that question, i really need help. thank you