# unable connect to server from application on device

Tags: android, connection, apk

I have problem with testing my application on device.  
I already successfully open the localhost in browser from my device, but when i enter my ip to connect my application with web service it didn't work.  
I always get the "unfortunately, [my apps name] has stopped" message.  
Anyone who knows about this problem, please help me. I really need help to solve this. thank you very much

logcat - i get it from usb debug on device

```
06-10 11:31:15.551: D/dalvikvm(14590): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-10 11:31:15.809: D/TextLayoutCache(14590): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
06-10 11:31:15.902: D/libEGL(14590): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-10 11:31:15.910: D/libEGL(14590): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-10 11:31:15.910: D/libEGL(14590): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
06-10 11:31:16.160: D/OpenGLRenderer(14590): Enabling debug mode 0
06-10 11:31:19.770: D/OpenGLRenderer(14590): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-10 11:31:22.309: D/OpenGLRenderer(14590): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-10 11:31:30.848: D/TryLoginCheck(14590): Here
06-10 11:31:30.848: I/System.out(14590): UserNametes
06-10 11:31:30.848: I/System.out(14590): passwordTes12345*
06-10 11:31:30.848: D/Parameters(14590): username=tes&password=Tes12345*
06-10 11:31:30.863: D/AndroidRuntime(14590): Shutting down VM
06-10 11:31:30.863: W/dalvikvm(14590): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd31f8)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at com.karismaelearning.Login.tryLogin(Login.java:128)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at com.karismaelearning.Login$3.onClick(Login.java:73)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14157)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-10 11:31:30.863: E/AndroidRuntime(14590):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 11:31:30.918: D/dalvikvm(14590): GC_CONCURRENT freed 237K, 6% free 6863K/7239K, paused 2ms+2ms
```

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy, I already installed the apk on my device, and i test it through wifi tethering, so how can I get the logcat? O.o. when i try in emulator it works successfully and didn't have any problem. thank you

Comment: You can read in documentation [how to test application on real device](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) so You can read logcat and do all other stuff DDMS offers.

Comment: Did you try setting any debug points or looking at logcat?

Comment: @Jack, i tried so many times in my emulator, my apps works fine no error. but when i installed in my phone, the application crash everytime. i already set the url to connect the web service with my ip. and i tested it in my browser device i can connect with server, but i tried from my apps it can't work. thank you

Comment: I understand that, I asked if you set any debug points in your app while it is running on your device, or if you have looked at the logcat while running on your device? The logcat generally points you to the exact line of code the failure happens. If your application is crashing, the next logical thing would be to look at the log file (logcat). Without you posting your logcat, no one can help you with your general description of "unfortunately, [my apps name] has stopped"

Comment: @Jack, I already posted my logcat, i debug my apps with usb tether and usb debug. and still force close. but when run in emulator it fine? o.O can you help me? thank you

Comment: @LawrenceChoy, I posted my logcat, please help me. thank you

Comment: @Gustek, I already posted my logcat. can you help me? what's wrong with my application? O.o thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` :

The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

do your code [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/1168654) in side `AsyncTask`

Comment: so, in every activity i must add asynctask? O.o

Comment: I will post my login.java for example. can you help me where must i create AsyncTask in my code? because i got confuse...

Comment: check this link here is sample: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Dhawal, this is my code [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017867/need-help-got-confuse-with-asynctask   .the part that make me confuse is, i have button login and `protected String Login` how to make AsyncTask from that two? O.o I tried but got confused. please help me. thank you

Comment: Dhawal, can I ask more? i have problem with receive messages, the messages become one in one big bubble. i need help how to split it. if you have time please look at this question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206453/how-to-split-the-chat-messages  thank you very much