# need help, got confuse with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new in android and i need to make AsyncTask, so my application can work on ICS. But after I read tutorials i still got confuse. Anyone, please help me to fix my code, i don't know what and where i must put in AsyncTask with my code like this. thank you

Login.java

```
package com.karismaelearning;

public class Login extends Activity {
    public Koneksi linkurl;
    String SERVER_URL;
    private Button login, register, setting;
    private EditText username, password;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsetting);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentSet = new Intent(Login.this, UrlSetting.class);
                startActivity(intentSet);
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentReg = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intentReg);
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String response = null;
                String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();

                Log.d("Check","Here");
                Log.d("Response",response);

                if(response.toLowerCase().contains("berhasil"))
                {
                    String nama = username.getText().toString();
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("nama", nama);

                    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Optional
                    //Kalau bisa dibuat constant untuk menghindari salah penulisan
                    String RoleError = "ROLE SALAH";
                    String UserError = "USER SALAH";

                    createDialog("Maaf", response.equals(RoleError) ? "Role Anda bukan Student!" : "Username Atau Password Salah!");
                }
            }
        });


    }
    protected String tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    {           
      Log.d(" TryLoginCheck ","Here");
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;
            String response = null;   
            String temp=null;
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   
            System.out.println("UserName"+mUsername+"\n"+"password"+mPassword);
            Log.d("Parameters",parameters);
            try
            {
                ;
                linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
                SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                SERVER_URL += "/mobile/Login.php";
                url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                temp=sb.toString();
                Log.d("Temp",temp);

                response = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Response",response);
               Log.d("Sb Value",sb.toString());
                isr.close();
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return response;
    }

    class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        public LoginTask(Login activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0){
    }
    private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(text)
        .create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

login.java - edited -> is it like this?

```
package com.karismaelearning;

public class Login extends Activity {
    public Koneksi linkurl;
    String SERVER_URL;
    private Button login, register, setting;
    private EditText username, password;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsetting);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentSet = new Intent(Login.this, UrlSetting.class);
                startActivity(intentSet);
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentReg = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intentReg);
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                new LoginTask().execute();
            }
        });

    }
    protected String tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword){           
      Log.d(" TryLoginCheck ","Here");
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;
            String response = null;   
            String temp=null;
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   
            System.out.println("UserName"+mUsername+"\n"+"password"+mPassword);
            Log.d("Parameters",parameters);
            try{
                linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
                SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                SERVER_URL += "/mobile/Login.php";
                url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                temp=sb.toString();
                Log.d("Temp",temp);

                response = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Response",response);
               Log.d("Sb Value",sb.toString());
                isr.close();
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)    {
                Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return response;
    }

    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String response = null;
        public LoginTask() {
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

            response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();
           return response;
        }
      protected void onPostExecute(String result){
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         Log.d("Check","Here");
            Log.d("Response",response);

            if(response.toLowerCase().contains("berhasil")){
                String nama = username.getText().toString();
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("nama", nama);

                newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
            }
            else{
                //Optional
                //Kalau bisa dibuat constant untuk menghindari salah penulisan
                String RoleError = "ROLE SALAH";
                String UserError = "USER SALAH";

                createDialog("Maaf", response.equals(RoleError) ? "Role Anda bukan Student!" : "Username Atau Password Salah!");
            }
      }
    }
    private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(text)
        .create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to execute your asynctask?

Comment: What's wrong with placing it the way you show us? I'm just weird how your stuffs work in ICS as I can identify a few syntax error.

Comment: @articles, I want to execute it when I click login button. Thank you

Comment: @blackneko on click on button new LoginTask().execute(params);  and then move all network related code in doInbackground()

Comment: @ChorWaiChun, I just confused how to make AsyncTask so I need help how to make it. and for ICS because i build my application in 2.3.3 it can't work on 4.0 so I need AsyncTask. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use like that

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
        progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {
        // do all login request here only 
      }
   @Override
        protected String onPostExecute(String arg0)
        {
         progressDialog.dismiss();

        // get the response here and show where you want
      }
```

Comment: @Sunil, I already did that, but why when I tried to tested it on my device still got error? O.o thank you very much. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020399/got-error-with-asynctask

Comment: @Siddharth, can you help me to solve this problem in this link? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020399/got-error-with-asynctask   I still got error with this AsyncTask.thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Put in your `OnClick` method

```
new LoginTask().execute(stringParam);
```

to execute your method after clicking element.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

You need to put your tryLogin() code into the doInBackground() method of the AsyncTask.

Incidentally, you should really take a look at your variable naming, the scope of your methods etc. Does tryLogin() really need to be protected? mUsername and mPassword are not member variables of the class, they are local variables.

http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: trylogin code or login code that I must put in do in background? O.o Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
    public Koneksi linkurl;
    String SERVER_URL;
    private Button login, register, setting;
    private EditText username, password;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsetting);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intentSet = new Intent(Login.this, UrlSetting.class);
                startActivity(intentSet);
            }
        });

        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentReg = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intentReg);
            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
               new LoginTask.execute();
            }
        });


    }
    protected String tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    {           
      Log.d(" TryLoginCheck ","Here");
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;
            String response = null;   
            String temp=null;
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   
            System.out.println("UserName"+mUsername+"\n"+"password"+mPassword);
            Log.d("Parameters",parameters);
            try
            {
                ;
                linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
                SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                SERVER_URL += "/mobile/Login.php";
                url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                temp=sb.toString();
                Log.d("Temp",temp);

                response = sb.toString();
                Log.d("Response",response);
               Log.d("Sb Value",sb.toString());
                isr.close();
                reader.close();


            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return response;
    }

    class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private Login activity;
        private int id = -1;

        public LoginTask(Login activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
        {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
        progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {
         String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();
           return response;
        }
      protected Void onPostExecute(String result){
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         if(response.toLowerCase().contains("berhasil"))
                {
                    String nama = username.getText().toString();
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class);

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("nama", nama);

                    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    String RoleError = "ROLE SALAH";
                    String UserError = "USER SALAH";

                    createDialog("Maaf", response.equals(RoleError) ? "Role Anda bukan Student!" : "Username Atau Password Salah!");
                }
      }
    }
    private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(text)
        .create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i get warning like this, LoginTask.execute cannot be resolved to a type . why is that? Thank you

Comment: make your LoginTask class public.

Comment: so i must separate between my login.java and logintask.java?

Comment: @blackneko i suggest first you read the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I already put public but why it still has the same warning :( . I already read that before i make this code but still confuse...

Comment: remove method from asynctask class.

Comment: which one that must be removed? O.o

Comment: which one that i must removed? O.o because i don't find any method??O.o thank you

Comment: Still the same, Segi it has the same error @_@..  i wanna ask, in my code there is code like this `Log.d("Check","Here");
                Log.d("Response",response);` where i must put this two?

Comment: Segi, I edited my codes, is it like that? i erase the the progress dialog and login activity. is it true like that? because there is no error anymore.