# got error with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I already use AsyncTask, but I don't understand why I still got error when i tested on my device (OS 4.0) . my apk build in 2.3.3 . I think i made the codes wrong, but i don't know where is my mistake. Anyone please help me, thank you very much

login.java

```
package com.karismaelearning;

    public class Login extends Activity {
        public Koneksi linkurl;
        String SERVER_URL;
        private Button login, register, setting;
        private EditText username, password;
        public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsetting);
            login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
            register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

            setting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentSet = new Intent(Login.this, UrlSetting.class);
                    startActivity(intentSet);
                }
            });

            register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentReg = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                    startActivity(intentReg);
                }
            });

            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new LoginTask().execute();
                }
            });

        }
        protected String tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword){           
          Log.d(" TryLoginCheck ","Here");
            HttpURLConnection connection;
           OutputStreamWriter request = null;

                URL url = null;
                String response = null;   
                String temp=null;
                String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   
                System.out.println("UserName"+mUsername+"\n"+"password"+mPassword);
                Log.d("Parameters",parameters);
                try{
                    linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
                    SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                    SERVER_URL += "/mobile/Login.php";
                    url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                    request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                    request.write(parameters);
                    request.flush();
                    request.close();            
                    String line = "";               
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    temp=sb.toString();
                    Log.d("Temp",temp);

                    response = sb.toString();
                    Log.d("Response",response);
                   Log.d("Sb Value",sb.toString());
                    isr.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)    {
                    Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return response;
        }

        public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String response = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
     String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
            String mPassword = password.getText().toString();

            response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();
       return response;
    }
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){

      if(result==null)
      {
          Toast.makeText(Login.this,"result is null- an error occured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
      else{

     Log.d("Check","Here");
        Log.d("Response",response);
     if(response.toLowerCase().contains("berhasil"))
            {
                String nama = username.getText().toString();
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(Login.this, MainPage.class);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("nama", nama);

                newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                //Optional
                //Kalau bisa dibuat constant untuk menghindari salah penulisan
                String RoleError = "ROLE SALAH";
                String UserError = "USER SALAH";

                createDialog("Maaf", response.equals(RoleError) ? "Role Anda bukan Student!" : "Username Atau Password Salah!");
            }
      }
  }
        }
        private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
            AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(text)
            .create();
            ad.show();
        }
    }
```

LogCat

```
06-10 16:50:00.082: D/TryLoginCheck(4534): Here
06-10 16:50:00.090: I/System.out(4534): UserName
06-10 16:50:00.090: I/System.out(4534): password
06-10 16:50:00.090: D/Parameters(4534): username=&password=
06-10 16:50:00.122: W/dalvikvm(4534): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd31f8)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at com.karismaelearning.Login$LoginTask.doInBackground(Login.java:151)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at com.karismaelearning.Login$LoginTask.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-10 16:50:00.129: E/AndroidRuntime(4534):     ... 5 more
06-10 16:50:05.192: D/OpenGLRenderer(4534): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-10 16:50:06.309: D/OpenGLRenderer(4534): Flushing caches (mode 1)
06-10 16:50:07.536: I/Process(4534): Sending signal. PID: 4534 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What does this do ? `response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim()`

Comment: i want to make the response is redirect to `protected trylogin()` .

Comment: @blackneko the error shown is because you can't call `Toast` from a background thread (see my answser on that).  However, if you want to solve the problem that's causing the exception, then I suggest you `Log.d(...)` the exception to help work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in tryLogin, when an Exception occurs you do:

```
 Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

that's wrong. The `Toast.show()` has to run on the UI Thread.

in

```
tryLogin() {

  try {

  }  catch(IOException e)  {
       return null;
  }

}
```

and in

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

    if (result == null) {
     Toast.makeText(Login.this,"result is null- an error occured"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
       result = result.trim();
       // the other stuff
    }

 }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
{
   String mUsername = username.getText().toString();
   String mPassword = password.getText().toString();          
   return tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
}
```

Comment: as suggested above use runonuithread or return a boolean value in doInbackground(param) and based on the result display toast in onPostExecute(result)

Comment: +1 for the update nice. and also the trim `response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim()` is the trim required?

Comment: when I show the toast is it like this? `Toast.makeText(Login.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` or just toast.show?

Comment: Toast.makeText(Login.this,"result is null"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @Raghunandan, i don't understand your question... did you meant, i must erase the trim()?

Comment: @blackneko the trim is for editext. so why this `tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim()`

Comment: @blackbelt, I tested again on my device the error still the same @_@ . what is wrong with my code? @_@

Comment: @blackbelt, can you show me where is my mistake? because i'm new in android so i can't understand. tank you very much

Comment: update your question with the changes you made to your code and the exception you are getting

Comment: @blackbelt, I already updated my codes and logcat. thank you very much

Comment: @blackneko what'on line 151 in Login.java?.

Comment: @Raghunandan, line 151 is `response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();`

Comment: move the trim() inside the onPostExcute in the else branch (response = response.trim();)

Comment: @blackneko i am not sure if this helps remove the trim() and also make sure your edittext are not null

Comment: @Raghunandan it happens because tryLogin() retunrs null

Comment: @blackbelt agreed the response might be null

Comment: remove the trim from tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword) and see my update

Comment: @blackbelt, do you mean i erase this line `response = tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword).trim();` ?? O.o and wrote it become in else `result = result.trim();`?

Comment: @blackbelt, it is not force close but when i try login, always throw the toast "result is null...." O.o

Comment: that's another issue. Do you have the internet permission?

Comment: @blackneko you are better off to start a new thread. accept the above answer and start a new question.

Comment: @blackbelt, why is that happen? O.o why it is become null? yes i already have internet permission O.o

Comment: @blackbelt, I tried it on my emulator it force close, but on my device it only throw toast?? O.o

Comment: @blackneko - see my second answer!

Comment: @blackbelt, I already post new issue in here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022040/get-null-in-asynctask   please look at it and please help me,thank you very much

Comment: @blackbelt, i need your help again for this problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161188/confused-to-put-code-in-asynctask  , if you have time can you please look at that question? because i'm not get the solution yet. i already read the documentation but still didn't understand how to put bundle in AsyncTask. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To work out why the routine tryLogin isn't working, I suggest following @BlackBelt's suggestion except for tryLogin() use:

```
tryLogin() {

  try {

  }  catch(Throwable e)  {
       e.printStackTrace();
       Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());
       return null;
  }

}
```

and look at the error messages produced.

Comment: I already post my new issue in here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022040/get-null-in-asynctask   please look at it, and please help me. thank you

Comment: I add your code in my codes, there is no message appear and when i test in device there is no logcat appear. O.o

Comment: I see that you've used my suggestion here in your new post.  In which case, it's customary to mark this suggestion as "useful".

Comment: There are already answers to your new question, pointing out that `response` is null.  In any case, if the new lines in my answer here aren't producing any output, then it means that the previous issue isn't occurring.  However, if and when it does re-occur, then just use the output to work out what's going wrong.  Unfortunately I have to log out now, so I'm not going to be available for the rest of today.  Good luck!

Comment: Stochastically, can i get your help for this problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161188/confused-to-put-code-in-asynctask  ,I already read the documentation like the other suggest but I still didn't understand how to code Asynctask that the param need bundle. if you have time, please look at this question and i need your help. thank you very much

Comment: @blackneko I had a go at answering your question :-).  If you've got any comments on my answer, I suggest you leave the comments on the answer rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

Login request put in doInBackground() method. And handle the response in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask

Comment: Login request is it like in my code or wrong? I didn't understand @_@

Answer (score 0):

The Toast won't work in the `catch` because the background thread can't access the user interface.  However, the `onPostExecute` does run on the main thread, so it does have access to the user interface and `toast` will work from there.

So I'd define a new class to hold the result of the AsyncTask, and set it up so that the class can either represent success or an error message.  Then get the `onPostExecute` to behave accordingly, depending on whether an error has occurred or not.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly, the error is due to  **Looper.prepare() is not being called manually  *or automatically from framework.***

Try calling

```
super()
```

in constructor of your

```
LoginTask
```

( From my understanding, When you extend AsyncTask and execute/start it from UI thread you wont get this exception because Looper will be prepared automatically by super class.)

or . A quick fix(Not recommended) : call Looper.prepare() in doInBackground

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try {
        Looper.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore. There can be only one Looper associated with thread
        // This happens when the current thread already has Looper associated with it
    }

    //TODO: Your original content of doInBackground(...)
}
```

p.s. If you are creating custom threads by extending *Thread* but not preparing *Looper* and using context of UI elements(For ex, To toast message) Android will throw Looper not prepared exception!