# confused to put code in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code to receive chat messages. but i got confused when i tried to place it in `AsyncTask`. i have warning `read cannot be resolved` for `read.readline()` when i put it in `postexecute` .  
i want to make this code work in background, to check there is any messages coming or not. and i wanna ask, to make the code always running in background is it use `AsyncTask` or there is any other way to do it?  
anyone please help me, i confused how to make it. thank you

receive message part

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
        URL url = null;
        try{
            linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
            SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
            SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatRoom.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3+"&idcm="+param4;
            url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
            //ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //add parameter
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

                //read content
                InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String msg = "tes";
                while(true)
                {

                    try {
                        msg = read.readLine();
                        Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                        //msgList.add(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                    if(msg == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showMessage(msg, false);
                    }
                }}
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
```

AsyncTask part that i tried - updated but get warning at `getintent()` where i must put these codes?

```
public class ReceivedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    final String param2 = bundle.getString("keyUserId");
    final String param3 = bundle.getString("keyChatsId");
     String param4 = bundle.getString("keyMessagesId");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        URL url = null;
        try{
            linkurl = new Koneksi(ChatRoom.this);
            SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
            SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatRoom.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3+"&idcm="+param4;
            url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
            //ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //add parameter
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

                //read content
                InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String msg = "tes";
                while(true)
                {

                    try {
                        msg = read.readLine();
                        Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                        //msgList.add(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                    if(msg == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showMessage(msg, false);
                    }
                }}
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
    }
```

ChatRoom.java - my full code

```
public class ChatRoom extends Activity {
    public Koneksi linkurl;
    String SERVER_URL;
    private EditText messageText;
    private TextView meLabel;
    private TextView friendLabel;
    private ViewGroup messagesContainer;
    private ScrollView scrollContainer;
/*    private Handler handler = new Handler();*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatpage);

        messagesContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.messagesContainer);
        scrollContainer = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollContainer);

        Button sendMessageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        /*final String paramnama = bundle.getString("nama");*/
        messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
        meLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meLabel);
        friendLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.friendLabel);
        meLabel.setText("me");


        final String param1 = bundle.getString("keyCourseId");
        final String param2 = bundle.getString("keyUserId");
        final String param3 = bundle.getString("keyChatsId");
         String param4 = bundle.getString("keyMessagesId");


        sendMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messages", messageText.getText().toString()));

                String response = null;

                try {
                    linkurl = new Koneksi(ChatRoom.this);
                    SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                    SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatKirimTeks.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3;
                   response = CourseHttpClient.executeHttpPost(SERVER_URL, postParameters);

                   String res = response.toString();

                   res = res.trim();

                   res = res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                   if(res.equals("1")){
                       String messageString = messageText.getText().toString();
                       showMessage(messageString, true);
                       messageText.getText().clear();
                   }else
                   {
                       createDialog("Maaf", "Messages Anda Gagal Terkirim");
                   }
                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                    messageText.setText(e.toString());  

                }

             }

        });


        HttpURLConnection connection;
        URL url = null;
        try{
            linkurl = new Koneksi(this);
            SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
            SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatRoom.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3+"&idcm="+param4;
            url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
            //ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //add parameter
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

                //read content
                InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String msg = "tes";
                while(true)
                {

                    try {
                        msg = read.readLine();
                        Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                        //msgList.add(msg);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                    if(msg == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showMessage(msg, false);
                    }
                }}
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }


    public class ReceivedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            URL url = null;
            try{
                linkurl = new Koneksi(ChatRoom.this);
                SERVER_URL = linkurl.getUrl();
                SERVER_URL += "/mobile/ChatRoom.php?idu="+param2+"&idch="+param3+"&idcm="+param4;
                url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
                //ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                //add parameter
                    //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                    HttpResponse httpRespose = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpRespose.getEntity();

                    //read content
                    InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String msg = "tes";
            while(true)
            {

                try {
                    msg = read.readLine();
                    Log.d("","MSGGG:  "+ msg);

                    //msgList.add(msg);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                if(msg == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    showMessage(msg, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void showMessage(String message, boolean leftSide) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(ChatRoom.this);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText(message);

        int bgRes = R.drawable.left_message_bg;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (!leftSide) {
            bgRes = R.drawable.right_message_bg;
            params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        }

        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        textView.setBackgroundResource(bgRes);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messagesContainer.addView(textView);

                // Scroll to bottom
                if (scrollContainer.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                    scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollContainer.getScrollX(), scrollContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
                }
                scrollContainer.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createDialog(String title, String text) {
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setMessage(text)
        .create();
        ad.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what does showMessage do? if you declare read in doInbackGround() its local. declare it a asynctask class variable and you can use it in onPostExecute

Comment: @Raghunandan showMessage , i use it to put the messages in bubble. thank you

Comment: you cannot update ui form doInbackground.

Comment: @Raghunandan, so where i must put it? O.o

Comment: if you want to display a toast or message use runonuithread or do it in onpostexecute

Comment: check this under the topic The 4 steps http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Raghunandan, my problem now is with the `getintent()` can you help me with that problem? thank you

Comment: what do you want pass values to asynctask? getIntent is for class that extends activity. so not possible in asynctask. So can you explain what you want?

Comment: @Raghunandan, huh? so i just put the code in asyncTask from this `HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();` and above from that code not necessary?

Comment: your comment is unclear. what is that exactly you wish to do?

Comment: @Raghunandan i want to put the receive part to AsyncTask, but i got confused from where i must put the codes... thank you

Comment: what do you mean by receive part?. Pls edit your question and state clearly what is needed. I am still not able to understand your commnet

Comment: @blackneko I am a little lost, but this is what I think is going on:
`ChatRoom.java` is your main. You got Strings in there. And you need to pass/use them in the Async class. And then..?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Bigflow, thank you for your respond. in ChatRoom.java i have the send message part and the receive msg part. the send part is work when i click the send button. but for the receive part not working, and in my opinion i must use the AsyncTask so the receive part always work in background to check the messages coming. but i got confused from where part i must put it, and where i must put it in Async. thank you very much

Comment: @blackneko Going to lunch first, then I take a look

Comment: @Bigflow, ok, have nice lunch. thank you

Comment: @blackneko if possible, go into this chat room, and we talk further, too much comments are getting in here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31938/async-talk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error message `read cannot be resolved` because Android forbids you to access the internet from the User Interface thread.  You have to do that in a background thread.  Indeed, the point of using `AsyncTask` is to keep the user interface thread as free as possible.

Whenever I use `AsyncTask`, I usually create a class to hold all the parameters of the task, and another class to hold the results.  Also, I make sure that the results class can represent any error conditions that may occur, e.g. exceptions thrown.  So the general template that I use looks something like this (NB: this is for when a progress report isn't required).

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    static class MyAsyncTaskParameters {
        // put all the parameters that the task will need here
    }

    void KickOffAsynctask(...) {  // various arguments as required by the task in hand
        MyAsyncTaskParameters params = new MyAsyncTaskParameters(...);  // package up all the parameters
        MyAsyncTask newtask = new MyAsyncTask();
        newtask.execute(params);
    }

    static class MyAsyncTaskResults {
        // put all the results that the task can generate here
        // NOTE: errors can occur in tasks, also exceptions
        //       can be thrown in tasks, so make it possible
        //       for this class to describe all error conditions that can occur
    }

    static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<MyAsyncTaskParameters, Void, MyAsyncTaskResults> {

        @Override
        protected MyAsyncTaskResults doInBackground(MyAsyncTaskParameters... params) {
            MyAsyncTaskResults results = new MyAsyncTaskResults();
            try {
                MyAsyncTaskParameters taskParameters = params[0];
                // This method will run in a background thread, so
                // do as much as possible of the AsyncTask here.
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // Set results object to indicate that an exception occurred.
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyAsyncTaskResults res) {
            // This method will run in the User Interface thread.
            // Use it to deal with the results stored in res.
            // If an error has occurred, the res object will have it stored
            // so take appropriate action, e.g. report to user.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Stochastically, Thank you very much for give respond for my question :D. thank you for explanation, i'll try that.. :D

Comment: @blackneko did that help at all?

Comment: @blackneko OK good :-), in which case it's conventional for you to upvote (to indicate that this answer was useful), and/or mark as 'the answer'?

Comment: Stochastically, can I ask you more question? i have problem in this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206453/how-to-split-the-chat-messages/17206516?noredirect=1#comment24930021_17206516  .i don;t know how to split the received messages. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask`, doing your work in `doInBackground(...)`. From there return your message, and handle the returned value in `onPostExecute(...)`.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String msg = "tes";  // Why? You have 'result' String reference one line above.
```

Don't read the stream in `onPostExecute`, do that as part of the background task. You'll otherwise block the UI thread.

See [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

Comment: so, i put all receive message part codes to `doInBackground(...)`? O.o thank you

Comment: Yes of course. What if your message is very very very very very very very very very long? You'll block the thread reading the stream.

Comment: owie.. my bad... i forgot to change it because i copied it from another codes.. sorry..

Comment: You'll block the thread reading the stream -> i don't understand this part. when i put the whole code to `doInBackground(...)` the postexecute is empty? or what i must put in there? O.o thank you

Comment: Reading the stream can be a long running task, and you might have multiples of such tasks to run. If you do it all on onPostExecute(...) it will prevent all other tasks on this thread running until it finishes reading. Since you're on the UI thread here, UI will freeze.

Comment: owh, thank you for the explanation. I updated my code with the new one , but get problem with `getIntent()`, where i must put those code? Thank you

Comment: Set the bundle reference in `onPreExecute()`. I really think you're trying to run before you can walk. Take your time studying the Android documentation, a lot of these questions will be answered before they're even asked.

Comment: hmmm, i think i got it, am i must make this code `String param2 = params[0];` in `doInBackground(...)`? and for param 3 it become [1] is it like that? O.o I just learned it from another question, but is it right like that? just want to make sure is it true like that or not.. thank you

Comment: No. In fact, usually `params` is actually just an array with one entry, `params[0]`.  To pass the result on to `onPostExecute()`, make it the return of the `doInBackground(...)` method. Again, you really should read the `AsyncTask` documentation - it's easier than speculating like this. You owe it to yourself (and me now).